# How to make decimal operations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, pi

I want to calculate pi with the chudnowsky algorithm and I want it to be precise so
I tried using Decimal module but I couldnt understand how I can use it. 
The code is

```
import decimal as dc
import math
dc.getcontext().prec = 54
sum1 = 0
for k in range(0, 100):
    a = (-1)**k*(math.factorial(6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
    b = (math.factorial(3*k))*(math.factorial(k))**(3)*(640320**(3*k))
    sum1 += a/b

sum1 = sum1/(426880*dc.Decimal("10005")**(1/2))
sum1= sum1**(-1)
print(sum1)
```

but it gives

```
Exception "unhandled TypeError"
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

I look the internet but couldnt find a good source that covers the things and gives examples. How can I square root decimals and if I want a Decimal type result and the operations to be mostly lossless how can I implement it to the code above? Its python 3.6
I am new here so I thank you for being tolerant to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pi calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284996/python-pi-calculation) which also uses chudnowsky

Answer (score 2):

I don't have too much experience with `decimal`, but the error you get is because you can't use the `**` operator with a decimal and a float. The solution is to make the exponent a `Decimal` too so instead of `dc.Decimal("10005")**(1/2)` you can do `dc.Decimal(10005)**dc.Decimal(1/2)`.

Basically, you can't combine `Decimals` and `floats` but `integers` are not a problem. You only need to be careful when you divide `integers` because that will result in `floats`, so you also need to change `sum1 += a/b` to `sum1 += dc.Decimal(a)/b`. When one operand is a `Decimal` the result will also be a `Decimal`. All the other numbers in your program are integers anyway so now it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The module `decimal` does not make sense to be used here. You are using `math.xxxx` functions, I cite the module documentation:

> The following functions are provided by this module. Except when explicitly noted otherwise, **all return values are floats**.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

[math.factorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial)  - returns float

Beside that: you recalculate constants:

```
dc.Decimal("10005")**(1/2) == 5002.5
```

No need to recalculate it - simply use `dc.Decimal('5002.5')` instead