# Python Division Many Decimal Places

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, decimal, division

Hi I'm wondering how to get python to output an answer to many more decimal places than the default value.

For example:
Currently print(1/7) outputs: 0.14285714285

I want to be able to output:0.142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a decimal class holding 1000 digits in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980840/how-to-define-a-decimal-class-holding-1000-digits-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

If you want completely arbitrary precision (which you will pretty much need to get at that level of precision), I recommend looking at the [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) module.

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps = 100
>>> mp.fdiv(1.0,7.0)
mpf('0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428579')
```

I suppose if all you want is to be able to do very simple arithmetic, the builtin `decimal` module will suffice.  I would still recommend `mpmath` for anything more complex.  You could try something like this:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=100))
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.0) / decimal.Decimal(7.0)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `decimal` module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Comment: You can also use formatting options to a certain extent: `print("%.100f" % (1.0/7))`

Comment: Try that. You'll find that it doesn't produce `0.142857` repeating.